# Transaction not getting confirmed because of transfer function even after making the address payable

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix

The finaliseRequest transaction is not getting confirmed no matter what I do. I am sure it is failing at the transfer function. I had made the address to address payable also and changed the function too. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
contract InsuranceClaim{
    struct Request {
        address payable insuranceRecipient;
        string personName;
        uint value;
        address payable hospitalRecipient;
        bool complete;

    }
    Request[] public requests;
    address public claimer;

    constructor (address creator) public{
        claimer = creator;
    }

    modifier restricted(){
        require(msg.sender==claimer);
        _;
    }

    function createRequest(string memory personName,address payable insuranceRecipient,uint value,address payable hospitalRecipient) public restricted{
        Request memory newRequest = Request({
            insuranceRecipient:insuranceRecipient,
            value:value,
            personName:personName,
            hospitalRecipient:hospitalRecipient,
            complete:false
        });
        requests.push(newRequest);
    }

    function finalizeRequest (uint index) public payable restricted{
        Request storage request = requests[index];
        require(!request.complete);
        request.hospitalRecipient.transfer(request.value);
        request.complete = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ethereum StackExchange! Could you tell us a bit more about what is the error you get when you try to run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't have any ether on your contract.
Add `payable` fallback function to your contract & transfer some ether there before transferring from it.

or make `finalizeRequest` request payable depending on your logic.

```
function finalizeRequest (uint index) public payable restricted {
```

Also, mark request complete before you transfer ether. It's security issue not related to your question.

Comment: I am sorry but payable was already there but it still isn't working

Comment: Also it is in remix so it already has ether in it

Comment: @Vikranth do you send enough ether on finalizeRequest call?

Comment: @Vikranth welcome, if you accept my answer I would appreciate this :)